# Build RSA-Signature of a file with libgmp

Tags: c, rsa, digital-signature, signature, gmp

I want to implement RSA-Signature where I can calculate the signature of a file and verify a signature of a file. Therefore I use the libary gmp. 
But when I want to print the data of the file, it always prints 0 even though the file is not empty. Here is my code:

```
//compiled with gcc rsa-sig.c -O3 -Wall -l gmp -o rsa-sig

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gmp.h> /* GNU Multi Precision library */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int r;
    mpz_t modulus;
    mpz_init(modulus);
    r=mpz_set_str(modulus, "FFFF",16); //just an example modulus
    mpz_t data;
    mpz_init(data);

    FILE * stream;
    stream = fopen("file.bin", "rb");
    r= mpz_inp_str(data, stream,16);

    mpz_mod(data,data,modulus);
    gmp_printf("%Zd\n",data);
}
```

I can't figure out why the output of that is 0. Maybe one of you guys have an idea.
Thanks!!

Comment: You could determine this on your own with even the simplest printf debugging, but `r= mpz_inp_str(data, stream,16);` returns zero. As it should.

Comment: I dont understand your hint. I don't want to print the output of r, but the output of "data". How can I do that?

Comment: It returns 0 because it's an error, your file does not contain hex characters but rather it is a binary file. `data` is not changed from its initial value of 0.